# If app installed then open app otherwise open play store

Tags: react-native

We are trying to generate a link that, when clicked in a browser, opens our App if it's installed otherwise go to the google play store for installation in react-native

Answer (score 0):

There is something called [Universal Link](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/universal-links-for-android-and-ios-1ddb1e70cab0) that might help you.
But the universal link will open your website if the app is not installed in the user's phone. Then you might have a web page with links for Google Play/ App Store

To do exactly what you want, you need to check some 3rd party services such as: branch.io or adjust.com

I hope this answer help you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using firebase dynamic links for android and IOS both.
for IOS-

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create

for Android-

> https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).